# How to add pattern with Image and Color in FabricJs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Is there any option to add pattern with Image AND Color?

Anytime, when I apply an image as a pattern, even though the image is transparent, Fabric adds it with some kind of "gray layer".

[Link to Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/0hke5jx6/3/)

```
var canvas = window.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 256,
    height: 256,
    fill: 'red'
});
canvas.add(rect);
rect.center().setCoords();

fabric.util.loadImage('https://assets-cdn.github.com/images/modules/site/integrators/slackhq.png', function (img) {
    rect.setPatternFill({
        source: img,
        repeat: 'no-repeat'
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the image has transparent background, you can use [`fabric.StaticCanvas`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html) as `fabric.Pattern`'s `source`:

```js
var imgPath = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png'
var imgColor = 'grey'

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')


fabric.Image.fromURL(imgPath, function(img) {
  var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas()
  patternSourceCanvas.add(img)
  patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundColor(imgColor, patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas))

  var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
    source: function() {
      return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
    },
    repeat: 'repeat'
  })

  // create a rectangle object
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: pattern,
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  })

  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
  canvas.add(rect)

})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Great Job !. Tnx!